# JWT verification for Swagger NodeJs API middleware

Tags: node.js, swagger, passport.js, swagger-codegen

I generated with Swagger a Node js API. I'm trying to add a jwt token check in my API to allow access to protected ressources. I would like to use something similar to passport js but I don't understand where I need to add the "passport.authenticate" method.

This is the way the app is initialized:

```
function initializeApp(swaggerOption, swaggerDoc) {

const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  swaggerTools.initializeMiddleware(swaggerDoc, function (middleware) {

    // Interpret Swagger resources and attach metadata to request - must be first in swagger-tools middleware chain
    app.use(middleware.swaggerMetadata());

    // Validate Swagger requests
    app.use(middleware.swaggerValidator());

    // Route validated requests to appropriate controller
    app.use(middleware.swaggerRouter(swaggerOption));

    // Serve the Swagger documents and Swagger UI
    app.use(middleware.swaggerUi());

    resolve(app);
    })
  });
  return p;
}
  exports.initializeApp = initializeApp;

  initializeApp(options, swaggerDoc ).then((app) => {
  // Start the server
  http.createServer(app).listen(serverPort, function () {
  console.log('Your server is listening on port %d (http://localhost:%d)', serverPort,     serverPort);
  console.log('Swagger-ui is available on http://localhost:%d/docs', serverPort);
  });
})
```

And an example of a controller

```
'use strict';

var utils = require('../utils/writer');
var Auth = require('../service/AuthService');

module.exports.authenticatePUT = function authenticatePUT (req, res, next) {
    var body = req.swagger.params['body'].value;
    Auth.authenticatePUT(body)
    .then(function (response) {
    utils.writeJson(res, response);
    })
    .catch(function (response) {
    utils.writeJson(res, response);
    });
  }
```

Since there is no route like so I can siply follow passport js's syntax

```
app.get ('/ profile',
  passport.authenticate ('bearer', {session: false}),
  function (req, res) {
    res.json (req.user);
  });
```

and no documentation (or I don't find) for middleware methods I don't find where I can add the jw token verification. If someone has some examples or explanations I would be verry happy :)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I am not using passport, but a simple example is like so:

In your routes the middleware is defined just as a function to run before proceeding further. It will implicitly receive the request data.

```
 app.post(
    '/api/object/create',
    auth.getToken, // << middleware evaluate
    objectController.create
  )
```

I have created my own middleware evaluation, it looks like this:

```
getToken: function (req, res, next) {
    const bearerHeader = req.headers['authorization']

    // Get the bearer token from the request
    if (typeof bearerHeader !== 'undefined') {
      const bearer = bearerHeader.split(' ')
      const bearerToken = bearer[1]
      req.token = bearerToken
      next()
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(401)
    }
  }
```

Now, this only checks to see if we have a token at all, it is a pretty simple check and is not in any way a security check.
This is because we may want to do more checks at the `objectController.create` function, about who this is, and what they should be able to do next. These checks could also be done within the above function, depending on your use case.

`objectController.create` receives the request, and the first thing it does is check the token

```
const currentUser = await currentUser(req.token)
```

which checks if this user is someone in the database, based on decoding from the jwt signing secret

```
async currentUser(token) {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.USER_AUTH_SECRET) // << very important never to commit this as a readable value in your repo, store in a local environment variable
    const user = await User.findOne({
      where: { email: decoded.user.email },
    })
    console.log(user.email)
    return user
  },
```

So, whilst this is not a Passport solution, it hopefully shows the basic process of middleware and then authenticating a jwt, which I think was your general question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const swaggerTools = require('swagger-tools');
const path = require('path');
const jsYaml = require('js-yaml');
const passport = require('passport');
const cors = require('cors');
const CONSTANTS = require('./constants');

module.exports = function initializeSwagger(app) {
// swaggerRouter configuration
    const swaggerRouterOptions = {
        swaggerUi: path.join(__dirname, '/swagger.json'),
        controllers: path.join(__dirname, '../controllers'),
        useStubs: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' // Conditionally turn on stubs (mock mode)
    };

    const swaggerDoc = jsYaml.safeLoad(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../api/swagger.yaml'), 'utf8'));

// Initialize the Swagger middleware
    swaggerTools.initializeMiddleware(swaggerDoc, function (middleware) {
        // Interpret Swagger resources and attach metadata to request - must be first in swagger-tools middleware chain
        app.use(middleware.swaggerMetadata());


        // *** Where you will call your JWT security middleware ***
        app.use(initializeSwaggerSecurity(middleware));


        //enable CORS
        app.use(cors());
        // Validate Swagger requests
        app.use(middleware.swaggerValidator());
        // Route validated requests to appropriate controller
        app.use(middleware.swaggerRouter(swaggerRouterOptions));
        // Serve the Swagger documents and Swagger UI
        if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "prod"){
            app.use('/docs', (req, res, next) => {
            });
          } else {
            app.use(middleware.swaggerUi());
          }
    });
};

function initializeSwaggerSecurity(middleware) {
    return middleware.swaggerSecurity({
        jwtAuth: (req, authOrSecDef, scopes, callback) => {
            passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}, (err, user, info) => {
                if (err) {                   
                    return callback(new Error(CONSTANTS.AUTHENTICATION.ERROR_MESSAGE_DEFAULT))
                };
                if (!user) {
                    // no user session, were we tampered? What happened? 
                    // @param info has that detail!
                    // console.log('url requested: ' + req.url + ' | raw headers: ' + req.rawHeaders);
                    // console.log('api: passport => jwt fn() initializeSwaggerSecurity(), rejected jwt token, token tampered or user session does not exist; failed to authenticate token: ', info);
                    return callback(new Error(CONSTANTS.AUTHENTICATION.ERROR_MESSAGE_TOKEN))
                }
                else {
                    req.user = user;
                    return callback();
                }
            })(req, null, callback);
        }
    });
};
```

Hope this helps you or anybody else who might be looking to implement this on Swagger 2.0